# How do I redirect after logging out in Service-Now?

Tags: redirect, servicenow

I need to log users out of Service-Now, and then redirect them to another part of Service-Now. I basically want to ensure that when users go to my Service-Now endpoint, they are logged out, so they have to have a fresh sign in.

I was using the Service-Now documentation, and haven't been able to get any of them to work. Does anyone already do this, or know how to?

From their examples, the first one logs them out, but doesn't redirect to the correct link inside of Service-Now. It just takes them home.

```
mycompany.service-now.com/logout.do?sysparm_goto_url=https://myredirecturl.com
```

The second example, redirects correctly, but doesn't log them out first. So they are still logged in when they get to the redirect url.

```
mycompany.service-now.com/logout_redirect.do?sysparm_url=https://myredirecturl.com
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Just an update on this - it seems to be a bug with Service-Now. We are working with their team for a resolution. I will post the solution here if there ends up being one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with the integration between my company and Service-Now. This was not able to be resolved without complex changes, so was put on hold temporarily.